# Why HttpContext.Current always null in user defined class in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've created a class named `MyLongRunningClass` that contain a method bellow:

```
 public string ProcessLongRunningAction(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files ,string id)
    {
        int currentIndex = 0;

        foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
        {
            currentIndex++;
            lock(syncRoot)
            {                
             string path=HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~//Content//images       //"+file.FileName);//Excecption is created here........
              file.SaveAs(path);
            }
          Thread.Sleep(300);
        }
        return id;
    }
```

From the controller this method is called with list of file to save in images directory. whenever `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~//Content//images//"+file.FileName)` is executed `NullReferenceException` thrown, and `HttpContext.Current` is always `null`. Same thing happen when I use session. I don't know whats wrong with the code.

Comment: Pass the destination path to the method, it helps with the separation of concerns.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you are running `ProcessLongRunningAction` on a separated thread.

However `HttpContext.Current` will return null when you are not running in the original request thread. This is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109526/the-cross-thread-usage-of-httpcontext-current-property-and-related-things).

You could use it if you manually set the context on every thread you create. This is discussed on similar questions in SO, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925227/access-httpcontext-current-from-threads-c-sharp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851532/c-anything-wrong-with-setting-httpcontext-current-in-a-parallel-thread).

However, given the code in your question it would be better if you just add a parameter for the path in that method, as Johann Blais suggested. You will then resolve the path in the original request thread and pass it  to that method, which can then run on a separated thread. This way your method does not depends on `HttpContext.Current`.

Comment: Thanks to who gave me valuable suggestion.