# How can I call a javascript function using C# in Content Grabber?

Tags: javascript, c#, recaptcha, content-grabber, grecaptcha

I am trying to call a Javascript function using C# in Content Grabber. (Content Grabber is a web scraping software).

The Javascript code is this:

```
$.definePage({
    idRecaptcha: null,

    init: function() {},

    carregarReCaptcha: function() {
        if(page.idRecaptcha == null) {
            var sitekey = $("#reCaptchaPublicKey").val();
            page.idRecaptcha = grecaptcha.render($("#tecRecaptcha")[0], {
                'callback' :  page.verifyCallback,
                'sitekey': sitekey
            });
        }
    },

    verifyCallback: function(response) {
        if(response) {
            $("#form").submit();
        }
    }
});

var onloadCallback = function() {
    page.carregarReCaptcha();
}
```

The function I want to call is "verifyCallback". This function essentially submits the recaptcha token, which will verify if the token I have entered is correct or not.

In my Content Grabber agent, I want to call this function, and I have this code, but it's giving me an error:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using Sequentum.ContentGrabber.Api;
public class Script
{
    //See help for a definition of CustomScriptArguments.
    public static CustomScriptReturn CustomScript(CustomScriptArguments args)
    {
        // retrieve page from current handler
        var page = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

        if (page == null)
        {
            // do something, e.g. throw exception
            return CustomScriptReturn.Pause();
        }

        // Place your script code here.
        // Return empty for no special action.
        string response = args.DataRow["Captcha"];
        string script = "page.verifyCallback('" + response + "');";

        // call ClientScript from existing page instance
        page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "page.verifyCallback", script, true);

        return CustomScriptReturn.Empty();
    }
}
```

When I compile it, it's returning this error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

It looks like I can't just delete `object sender, EventArgs e`

I'm not really familiar with JS or C#, so I would appreciate any help I can get. Thank you so much!

Comment: You've now got a method defined within a method - this isn't allowed in C#. Remove the `protected void callback(object sender, EventArgs e)` and associated braces from the CustomScript method. You are also returning from your CustomScript method before any of the other code runs. Move your `return` statement to the end of the CustomScript method.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. It compiled well, but when I ran it, I got the error:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Is it because we omitted the declaration "object sender, EventArgs e"?

Comment: Its difficult to say without you giving us the line number from the Stack Trace in the runtime error output. Looking at the code, it could be because the `page` object is null. Your code checks to see if its null, but then doesn't do anything about it and the code is allowed to continue...

Comment: I see. I added a pause action if the page is null. I ran the script, and my agent did not pause (so I assume page is not null), but I still get the object error. About the line number, unfortunately, I can't find it. When I'm compiling it, no error registers. It's just when I run it with the agent that the error appears, and there's no note of the line number in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because you're trying to use `ClientScript` instance from a class which not inherited from `System.Web.UI.Page` (base class for code-behind pages). As long as you have access to [`HttpContext.Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.current?view=netframework-4.7.2), you can retrieve `Page` instance from its handler property (i.e. [`CurrentHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.currenthandler?view=netframework-4.7.2)) and use `ClientScript` as in example below:

```
public class Script
{
    //See help for a definition of CustomScriptArguments.
    public CustomScriptReturn CustomScript(CustomScriptArguments args, object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // retrieve page from current handler
        var page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

        if (page == null)
        {
            // do something, e.g. throw exception
        }

        // Place your script code here.
        // Return empty for no special action.
        string response = args.DataRow["Token"];
        string script = "verifyCallback('" + response + "');";

        // call ClientScript from existing page instance
        page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "verifyCallback", script, true);
        return CustomScriptReturn.Empty();
    }
}
```

**Update:**

As for explaining the second error after edit, it occurred because you're declaring a method named `callback` inside `CustomScript` method, which is not valid (and the `return` statement must be on the last). If the `sender` and `EventArgs` handlers are unnecessary then simply omit them. Here is an example to properly return `CustomScriptReturn`:

```
public static CustomScriptReturn CustomScript(CustomScriptArguments args)
{
    // retrieve page from current handler
    var page = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

    if (page == null)
    {
        // do something, e.g. throw exception
    }

    // Place your script code here.
    // Return empty for no special action.
    string response = args.DataRow["Captcha"];
    string script = "page.verifyCallback('" + response + "');";

    // call ClientScript from existing page instance
    page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "page.verifyCallback", script, true);

    return CustomScriptReturn.Empty();
}
```

Related issue:

[An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.ClientScript.get'](https://forums.asp.net/t/1950255.aspx?An%20object%20reference%20is%20required%20for%20the%20non%20static%20field%20method%20or%20property%20System%20Web%20UI%20Page%20ClientScript%20get%20)

Comment: Thank you @tetsuya for you quick response. I have applied all of your suggestions and was able to compile it without error. However, when I ran it in Content grabber, I get this error:
Error executing custom script. Error: The method CustomScript must have exactly one parameter of type CustomSriptArguments. 

It appears the customScript can't have the declarations "object sender, EventArgs e"

I tried moving these definitions inside the customScript, but it's giving even more errors. Please see the original question. I have modified the script there. 
Again, thank you so much!

Comment: Edited with some explanation about method you're using and placement of `return` statement.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. It compiled well, but when I ran it, I got the error:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Is it because we omitted the declaration "object sender, EventArgs e"?

Comment: That's `NullReferenceException`, but sounds unrelated with absence of `sender` and `EventArgs` (they're used for event handlers). Try checking where and when the exception being thrown.

Comment: I see. I added a pause action if the page is null. I ran the script, and my agent did not pause (so I assume page is not null), but I still get the object error. About the line number, unfortunately, I can't find it. When I'm compiling it, no error registers. It's just when I run it with the agent that the error appears, and there's no note of the line number in the error message.

Comment: If that `NullReferenceException` is a runtime error, try debug with the agent enabled. You can enable debugging feature of the web server or attach debugger to process handler and return detailed error message (check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-debugging-for-aspnet-applications)).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto The HttpContext.Current is == null , so the var page = ... stuff returns an object null error. It doesnt even get to if(page == null) , so it doesnt even pause . As far as the rest of stack says its because its running on a separate thread.

Comment: You're stated that the process running in separate thread, then it matches [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323448/why-httpcontext-current-always-null-in-user-defined-class-in-asp-net-mvc). Consider read [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925227/access-httpcontext-current-from-different-threads) for multi-threaded scenario.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Tetsuya's answer, it looks like you'll have an issue with the Javascript you're passing to RegisterStartupScript.

I don't think you'll be able to just call "verifyCallback" because that is a function defined within the scope of the `$.definePage({})` call.

So you'll need to dig deeper into that and find out if the `verifyCallback` function is  exposed publically.

Based on this code:

```
var onloadCallback = function() {
    page.carregarReCaptcha();
}
```

I'd say you'd need to call:

```
page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "page.verifyCallback", script, true);
```

Comment: Thank you @JTech for you quick response. I have applied all of your suggestions and was able to compile it without error. However, when I ran it in Content grabber, I get this error:
Error executing custom script. Error: The method CustomScript must have exactly one parameter of type CustomSriptArguments. 

It appears the customScript can't have the declarations "object sender, EventArgs e"

I tried moving these definitions inside the customScript, but it's giving even more errors. Please see the original question. I have modified the script there. 
Again, thank you so much!