# Logging HttpContext.Current data

Tags: asp.net, .net, httpcontext

HttpContext.Current is not serializable but I want to capture Request, Query string parameters, Session data, etc for some debugging purposes on PRODUCTION.

In other words, I want to manually collect all the information possible. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can not serialize the HttpContext. To achieve this you should create a custom class to encapsulate the information that you want out of the HttpContext and from there you can log them into file.

see this post: ["System.Web.HttpContext cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723919/system-web-httpcontext-cannot-be-serialized-because-it-does-not-have-a-paramete)

This link may helps for Tracing:
http://odetocode.com/articles/242.aspx

Comment: I saw that but I was hoping for some shared code to avoid grunt work.

Comment: You can enable Tracing in web.config, to get some info. If we want to debugging specific case.